# How can I pass data between GSP and controller in Grails without storing in the database?

Tags: grails, controller, gsp

Is it possible to enter data in the GSP view and use this data in the controller inside the program to do some operations without storing this data in the domain. For example I have a g:textField  and I enter my name. I want to be able to use the name that I enter in the controller to manipulate.

Comment: it's not clear what you asking. do you mean call a method from gsp? or send data to server from resulting html in browser?

Comment: For example, you have a <g:textField> and you put data in your view. I want to get the data that I enter in the gextField and use it in my controller. Do you understandme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the data passed from a view to a controller has to line up with any particular Domain. There are a couple of ways you could do this.

the view:

```
<g:textField name="name" />
```

the controller:

```
class SomeController {
  def someAction() {
    def name = params.name
    // do something with name
  }
}
```

You could also use a [Command Object](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/single.html#commandObjects).

the command object:

```
@Validateable
class SomeCommand {
  String name

  static constraints = {
     name nullable: false
  }
}
```

the controller:

```
class SomeController {
  def someAction(SomeCommand someCommand) {
    if (!someCommand.hasErrors()) {
      def name = someCommand.name
      // do something with name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One question more @gregg. And If I want to use this data in my Services, How can I do it?? Thanks

Comment: Create a new question and I'll provide an answer.